# Azure Active Directory Logout with ADAL library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I used the my Azure Active Directory to protect my web API and I create a native application in the Azure management portal. This native application is basically a MVC web application and I use the ADAL library to get the token and call the api with that token. The code I used to get the token is shown below:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(resourceID, clientID, redirectURI);
string accessToken = ar.AccessToken;
```

Now I need to logout and switch to another user but somehow the user credentials are remembered by the system. I clear the token cache in the authentication context and post logout api request as follows where *** is my tenant ID.

```
//Log out after api call
ac.TokenCache.Clear();

string requestUrl = "https://login.windows.net/***/oauth2/logout";

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

The api call succeeds but the logout doesn't work.
What should I do to logout and switch to another user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this would work. You would need to redirect the user to logout URL for logout to work.

Here's how you can create a logout URI:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}`

Where:

- **{0}** - Fully qualified name of your Azure Active Directory e.g. yourad.onmicrosoft.com or tenant id.
- **{1}** - The URL of your application where a user must be redirected back after the logout is complete. This should be properly URL encoded.

Comment: I tried calling this logout in the iOS ADAL, but it is not sufficient to prevent an exception on a account change. Anybody any success in login/logout using ADALiOS and two different accounts?

Comment: In the case of Mobile app. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

If you goal is to sign in a s a different user, you don't strictly need to log out the first user from its session with Azure AD. You can pass PrompBehavior.Always in your AcquireToken call, so that you will be guaranteed to prompt the user with a clean credential gathering UX.
Note: if you want to wipe every trace of the first user from the app you can keep the cache cleanup code you have. ADAL allows you to keep tokens for multiple users tho, hence if your app as multi-user functions this might be useful - the catch is that if you do so, at every AcquireToken you'll have to also specify which user you want a token for or ADAL won't know which one to return. If you don't need multiple users at once, the cache cleanup + PromptBehavior.Always remains the easiest path.

Comment: Could you confirm that this currently works? I use the iOS ADAL library, with the AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS request. I cannot logon with any other user then the first user I tested with: (ADAL Error: 19, Different user was authenticated. status: 2).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312710/adal-for-ios-exception-with-a-different-user-sign-on

Comment: Confirmed for Android lib.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for clear cache :

```
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        mAuthContext.getCache().removeAll();
```

Comment: This is a part of the solution, they have changed the last part of removing Tokens from the cache: `mAuthContext.getCache().clear();` But this solution actually works!