# ADAL Logout across multiple apps in same broswer?

Tags: angular, reactjs, active-directory, adal

Using ADAL in a react(react-adal) and angular(MsAdalAngular6Service) apps, 
SSO works for both apps(Loggin in one app, autmatically logs in into the other),

but logout functionality restricted to single app.

If I logout from the react app, the anguar app stays loggedin in the same browser window.(vice-versa)

How do i make sure I logout from all applications on the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Logging out of one application will not logout from another application (both using ADAL) as user has not logged out from another application explicitly.

Take the analogy of any other oauth2 application like google login. 
Say website A and website B both uses google login for sign-in users into their website. If user is not logged into google, first application when try to login will take the user to login into google and then user is signed into website A. Since user is already logged into google, when user tries to login using website B, s/he is directly logged in. But logging out website A won't logout the user from website B.

One of the option which you can try doing is to logout the user from Active Directory also when he logs out from one of the application (See - [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172898/azure-active-directory-logout-with-adal-library)) but this won't logout the user from another application as the website has already acquired the token to be used.

Hope I explained it in simple terms.

Comment: Hey, I get your point and was under same impression initially,  but i've tried this situation with gmail and youtube, where logging off from one application logs user off of the other apps in the browser as well. I will try the option you've given.

Comment: When I referring to oauth applications, I referring to stack overflow (if you use gmail to login into it). Whether you logs out of google, stackoverflow session will still work. Youtube and Gmail works on same session and hence if one of the session is expired, other application session is also expired. (which is sharing session information not using oauth2 or similar).

Comment: If this answer helps, you can vote the answer and accept the answer. @user5667392

Comment: the answer helps, but doesn't solve the question, so did not accept the answer to avoid confusion. Can't upvote because i got no stack overflow cred apparently. thanks for the help though